# move and Rename file to folder Powershell

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

I have some pdf's in a folder that I need to organize them like this:

PDF name: 123.12.123.pdf ; 102030_01.pdf; 102030_02.pdf; 123.4512.34561.23412.pdf

Now I need to create folders with the filename (without the characters removed, ex: 12345123456123412) and rename them to the following pattern: ex: P12345123456123412_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001.pdf

for this I have used the following code which works very well:

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
If "%~1" == "" GoTo :EOF
For %%G In (%*) Do (For %%H In ("%%~G") Do If "%%~aH" Lss "-" (
        Echo Error! %%G no longer exists.
        %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 /NoBreak 1>NUL
    ) Else If "%%~aH" GEq "d" (For %%I In ("%%~G\*.pdf") Do Call :Sub "%%~I"
    ) Else If /I "%%~xG" == ".pdf" (Call :Sub "%%~G"
    ) Else (Echo Error! %%G is not a PDF
        %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 /NoBreak 1>NUL))
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Set "basename=%~n1"
Set "basename=%basename:.=%"
MD "%~dp1%~n1" 2>NUL
If Not ErrorLevel 1 Move /Y %1 "%~dp1%~n1\P%basename:-=%_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001_Volume%~x1"
Exit /B
```

I drag the pdfs into the .bat and it does the adjustment.

It happens that there is a case that I am not able to handle. Some pdfs need to be in the same folder, for example in the following case:
PDF name: 102030_01.pdf; 102030_02.pdf;

Note that the pdfs have the same number, only after the _ that we have the difference. In this case you would need to create a folder with the name:102030
And move the two files into it, modifying their name as follows:
102030_01.pdf -> P102030_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_**S00001**.pdf
102030_02.pdf -> P102030_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_**S00002**.pdf

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:Sub
Set "basename=%~n1"
Set "basename=%basename:.=%"
if /i "%basename%" neq "%basename:_=%" goto sub2
MD "%~dp1%~n1" 2>NUL
If Not ErrorLevel 1 Move /Y %1 "%~dp1%~n1\P%basename:-=%_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001_Volume%~x1"
Exit /B 

:sub2
for /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%b in ("%basename%") do (
 MD "%~dp1%%b" 2>NUL
 ECHO Move /Y %1 "%~dp1%%b\P%basename:-=%_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S000%%c_Volume%~x1"
)
Exit /B
```

Always test on dummy data first.

This code `echo`es the proposed move. After verification, remove the `echo` keyword to activate.

**Caution:** My reading of the code is that `-` should be removed from the basename in the new name, and that `_Volume` should be appended to the name part, which is not shown in your examples.

Essentially, if the basename contains `_` then goto `sub2`.

`sub2` partitions the name in `basename`, assigning the first part to `%%b` and the second to `%%c` (See `for /?` from the prompt for documentation)

Then the directory is created

The `md` will object if the directory already exists, hence the `2>nul` in the original code (suppresses error messages)

If `md` found that error **in the original** then this appears to be a problem, so the `move` is not executed. In the new version, it **is** expected that the directory may already exist, so the `errorlevel` processing has been removed.

Comment: I really forgot to mention _volume in the examples, I tried to use the script you passed and it didn't work, nothing happens. See, I don't understand what you mean by "After verification, remove the echo keyword to activate." maybe here I was wrong. I just copied your code and inserted it into mine, removing my sub. @Magoo

Comment: First thing - using your original code, `102030_01.pdf` should have been moved to `P102030_01_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001_Volume.pdf` in subdirectory `102030_01` Did this happen with the new code? The new code should have created subdirectory `102030`. Did this happen? Since the `move` command is being `echo`ed, you would likely need a new line `pause` directly before the `exit /b` line to see the data that is `echo`ed, It's normal to simply `echo` a `move` command so that you can see the command and correct the code if the command is incorrect.

Comment: This is "verification". Once you have verified that the command is correct, you remove the pause and the `echo` which caouses the `move` command to be executed instead of being reported to the screen. In this way, if the command is incorrect, no harm is done.

Comment: With the proposed changes nothing happens, if I remove this line from your code (if /i "%basename% neq "%basename:_=%" goto sub2) the folder is created but as before, without treating the _01

Comment: There was an error on that `if` line - a missing `"` - fixed now.

Comment: Thank you very much friend, the folder 102030 was created, but the files 102030_01 and 102030_02 were not moved, do you know what is missing? @Magoo

Comment: Given that you have the `pause` and `echo` in place, there should have been some data `echo`ed to the screen. This should be a `move` command. Was thus reported to the screen, and if so, was it as expected?

Comment: pops up:  Move /Y "C:\e-processo\importacao\4774700104320196_1.pdf" "C:\e-processo\importacao\4774700104320196\P4774700104320196_1_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S0001_Volume.pdf"
Press any key to continue. . .
Move /Y "C:\e-processo\importacao\4774700104320196_2.pdf" "C:\e-processo\importacao\4774700104320196\P4774700104320196_2_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S0002_Volume.pdf"
Press any key to continue. . .

Comment: But the file is not moved @Magoo

Comment: The `move` commands that appeared seem to be correct - although your post states `..._01.pdf` and your file is `_1.pdf` consequently, the new filename is `..._S0001_...` whereas your post states `_S00001_` (one fewer `0` character). Only you know whether this is correct. If it's correct, remove the `pause` and the `echo` before the `move`. We use this as a check to ensure the correct instruction is generated. Executing an incorrect instruction may lead to losing data. It's a safety mechanism.